# Weird NullPointerException for attempting to display a List of Strings

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio, nullpointerexception

I've spent hours attempting to debug this code. Basically I have `MainActivity` with the default code you get after starting a new project.
And this is my `MainActivityFragment`:

```java
package app.xxxx.github.io.sunshine;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String[] fakeData = new String[]{
                "Today - Sunny - 88/63",
                "Tomorrow - Foggy - 70/46",
                "Weds - Cloudy - 72/63",
                "Thurs - Rainy - 64/51",
                "Fri - Foggy - 70/46",
                "Sat - Sunny - 76/68"
        };
        List<String> weatherData = Arrays.asList(fakeData);
        ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_forecast,
                    R.id.listview_forecast, weatherData);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        ListView listview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        listview.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        return rootView;}}
```

As you can see, I'm just attempting to show some dummy strings to the screen.

Here is `FragmentMain.xml`:

```xml
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="app.xxxx.github.io.sunshine.MainActivityFragment"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listview_forecast" />

</FrameLayout>
```

and `list_item_forecast.xml`:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/list_item_forecast_textview" />
```

Here is what the Stack Trace says:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                  Process: app.xxxx.github.io.sunshine, PID: 4652
>                                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object reference
>   at
>   android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:399)
>   at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:369)

Sorry if it got a little bit ugly but had to give enough context for the problem. Thanks.

Comment: You're passing the wrong `R.id` in the `ArrayAdapter` constructor call. It needs to be the ID of the `TextView` in the list item layout - `R.id.list_item_forecast_textview` - or just remove that argument, if the layout is just the `TextView`.

Comment: The **id** being `R.id.list_item_forecast_textview`.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the id of the list_item_TextView  but  not the ListView itself.
So change your code as

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_forecast,
                R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, weatherData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you giving wrong id of textview in adapter

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_forecast,
                    R.id.listview_forecast, weatherData);
```

so replace this line with

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_forecast,
                    R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, weatherData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix your TextView's id into the declaration of `ArrayAdapter`:

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_forecast,
                        R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, weatherData);
```

Or, use the built-in TextView as following:

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_forecast,
                        android.R.id.text1, weatherData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using this constructor to create adapter instance.

```
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param context The current context.
     * @param resource The resource ID for a layout file containing a layout to use when
     *                 instantiating views.
     * @param textViewResourceId The id of the TextView within the layout resource to be populated
     * @param objects The objects to represent in the ListView.
     */
    public ArrayAdapter(Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, @IdRes int textViewResourceId,
            @NonNull T[] objects) {
        this(context, resource, textViewResourceId, Arrays.asList(objects));
    }
```

It uses

```
@param textViewResourceId The id of the TextView within the layout resource to be populated
```

Because you are using custom layout, so you have to pass right textView id to populate data

simply change

```
ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_forecast,
                R.id.listview_forecast, weatherData);
```

to

```
ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_forecast,
                R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, weatherData);
```